# Joomla index redirect

Tags: php

I want to redirect the `index.php` to `index.html`. But in the `index.html` user has 2 options, 1. to go to a specific section (or) 2. go to actual `index.php` i.e. our actual site is running with `index.php`, but we want to highlight a section, so first we want the user to come to `index.html` & go to mainsite if he wants to.

How can I do this? I have tried htaccess, but it is giving an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat inelegant solution is to move your Joomla site into a subdirectory (say /site), leaving your index.html page where it is. The downside is that this would break any links pointing to specific locations on your site.

Comment: thankyou waggers, i was just preparing for that. I think there is no workaround.